# Comparing Python Data-frames

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, compare

I have two data frames, e.g.,

```
df_1:
index A  B   C  D
1     2  5   9  12
2     9  8   13 22
3     0  44  3  1

and
df_2:
index  A   C
1      12  40
2      9   13
3      16  1
4      0   21
```

I am looking for a way to compare these two dfs and the final product should be rows in df_1 such that the values in column A and C are present in df_2, e.g.

```
Final_df:

index A B C D
2    9  8 13 22
```

I have tried,

```
Final_df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['A','C'], how='left', indicator='Exist')                      
Final_df['Exist'] = np.where(Final_df.Exist == 'both', True, False)
Final_df = Final_df[Final_df['Exist']==True]
```

But it doesn't give the expected results. Your suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to have an inner merge.

```
df_1.merge(df_2, on=['A', 'C'], how='inner')
```

```
   A  B   C   D
0  9  8  13  22
```

Comment: yes, that is correct.